# Jquery only works in the header.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm reading up all I can on jQuery, but this week I like(need) to finish a website and I could find a solution to this problem in the last eight hours.

**Setting**

I'm using a ajaxed wp theme which I'm customising to my own liking.

**Problem**

I've wrote a simple function to change the header image and the header text when you click on the main navigation links.

The function does work in the `header.php` but doesn't work in a custom front page (`main_navp.php`) I've included in `index.php`.
On `navp.php` there's an image when onclicked should do the same changes as a click on the nav bar.

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

 <div id="main-content"><div id="inside">

 <?php get_template_part('main_navp'); ?>

 <?php if// HERE IS THE WP LOOP (not used so left out) //?>

<div class="pagination">
   <span class="older"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></span>
 <span class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></span>
 </div>``

<?php else : ?>

<h1>no posts...</h1>

<?php endif; ?>

</div></div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The function is included in the `header.php` in the ..`head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {

            $("a[title='Gigs']").click(function()
            {
            $("#main_logo").css("background-image","url(<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/header/gig_header_flip.png)");
            $("a#nav_text").html("Gigs");

            });


            $("a[title='Bio']").click(function()
            {
            $("#main_logo").css("background-image","url(<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/header/play_header.png)");
            $("a#nav_text").html("Biography");

            });

            $("a[title='Gitaarles']").click(function()
            {
            $("#main_logo").css("background-image","url(<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/header/les_header.png)");
            $("a#nav_text").html("Gitaarles");

            });


            $("p[id='les_mp']").live("click", function()
            {
            $("#main_logo").css("background-image","url(<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/header/les_header.png)");
            $("a#nav_text").html("Gitaarles");

            });


            $("li[id='homew']").click(function()
            {
            $("#main_logo").css("background-image","url(<?php   bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/header/header_arty.png)");
            $("a#nav_text").html("Home");

            });


        });


        </script>
```

In the `main_navp.php` (included in `index.php` afther the `header.php`) the function does not work on this item. But it should be triggered by `$("p[id='les_mp']").live("click", function()` as seen above.

```
   <div id="boxred_b">

  <div class=head_box><a>Gitaarles</a></div>

      <p class="homeles" id="les_mp">
       <a href="/gitaarles"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/les_mp.jpg" /></a>
      </p>
```

The main jquery is caled in the header.php

```
<script src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jjquery-1.5.2.min.js'></script>
```

In the footer.php are all of the rest of the jquery functions.

```
 <!-- http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-urlinternal-plugin/ -->
<script src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.ba-urlinternal.min.js'></script>

    <!-- http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ -->
    <script src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.address-1.3.2.min.js'></script>

    <script>

        // Original JavaScript by Chris Coyier
        // Updated October 2010 by Stewart Heckenberg & Chris Coyier

        $(".home li.home").removeClass("home").addClass("current_page_item");
        $("#column-wrap").append("<img src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ajax-loader.png' id='ajax-loader' />");

        $("#s").focus(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "Search...") {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });

        if ($(".widget_categories li").length%2 != 0) {
            $(".widget_categories ul").append("<li><a>&nbsp;</a></li>");
        }

        if ($(".widget_tag_cloud a").length%2 != 0) {
            $(".widget_tag_cloud").append("<a>&nbsp;</a>");
        }

        // The reason this JavaScript is in footer.php instead of its own file is basically the next line.
        var base             = '<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>',
            $mainContent     = $("#main-content"),
            $ajaxSpinner     = $("#ajax-loader"),
            $searchInput     = $("#s"),
            $allLinks        = $("a"),
            $el;

        $('a:urlInternal').live('click', function(e) { 

            $el = $(this);

            if ((!$el.hasClass("comment-reply-link")) && ($el.attr("id") != 'cancel-comment-reply-link')) {         
                var path = $(this).attr('href').replace(base, '');
                $.address.value(path);
                $(".current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_item");
                $allLinks.removeClass("current_link");
                $el.addClass("current_link").parent().addClass("current_page_item");
                return false;
            }

            // Default action (go to link) prevented for comment-related links (which use onclick attributes)
            e.preventDefault();

        });  

        $('#searchform').submit(function() {  
            var s = $searchInput.val();
            if (s) {
                var query = '/?s=' + s;
                $.address.value(query);  
            }
            return false;
        });  

        $.address.change(function(event) {  
            if (event.value) {
                $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
                $mainContent
                    .empty()
                    .load(base + event.value + ' #inside', function() {
                        $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
                        $mainContent.fadeIn();
                    });  
            } 

            var current = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + location.pathname;
            if (base + '/' != current) {
                var diff = current.replace(base);
                location = base + '/#' + diff;
            }

        });                 

    </script>

  </div>
```

I've tried to keep things as short as possible. If you like any more information please ask.

-update

using the live function in the header doesn't seem to solve the problem.
I'm using XAMPP to run the website locally. If it helps I could make an online wp installation or could provide the webside (html/java) source.

Comment: I recommend not to post your complete website. First make a good hypothesis on what could be wrong on your site and show that.

Comment: Your right, but my lack of knowledge makes that a bit complicated for me. I think the error is in the include php and the right use of the live function. Maybe the use of the ajax code in the footer has an influence on that process so that's why I've included it as well.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are Ajax-ing your page, the events are not subscribed to your new elements. Try using the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) command.

Also, is this ok?
`$("p[id='les_mp']").click(, function()`...
Don't know for sure about that comma.

Comment: thank you. The click(, function() . is a remain of when i tried the live function which din't worked when i tried it.

Comment: @Rob, So does it solve your problem? Are you using a simple .click() or a .live?

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried is as a .live() function as well as an ,click(). Currently i use the .live() function.  Should the live function be insert in the $(document).ready(function() { usedhere }?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using the live function in the code like this.

```
$("p[id='les_mp']").live("click", function()
{
$("#main_logo").css("background-image","url(<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/header/les_header.png)");
$("a#nav_text").html("Gitaarles");

});
```

in the

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
    { .... }
```

in header.php

Still it doesn't work when be onclicked in main_nav.php
When I put the code out of the main_nav in to the header.php 
it works.

Comment: if you have a comment or an update on your question, just edit your question. Do not answer your question with another question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the method in the link below to refactor the ajax stuff to a separate file. Not sure if it helps with the original problem, but i've seen things work after doing that http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#js-global
basically you get your url into a variable that is being printed and your scripts have access to using wp_localize_script